# Why is my external stylesheets not linking on mobile device?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I've noticed others have had this issue and I tried the suggested methods I could find, even tried the @import rule in in a  tag inside the header.  But no dice.  Not sure if I need the http-equiv meta tag, but it was suggested on another site.  Here is a sample of the header on the index html file:

```
<!doctype html>
```

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>Thephotographerseye: Greg Holloway Photography</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Links to stylesheet and google fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/fonts.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Charm:wght@400;700&family=Roboto:wght@300;400;700&display=swap">
```

And here are a few of the media queries in the css file:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .brandImg .material-icons {font-size: 18px;}
    #openingAnimation::before {width: 60%;}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
    .navlinks {
        display: flex; 
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    .navlinks a {flex: 50%;}
}
```

I only did the front end design, and it was uploaded to my friends domain through Dreamweaver.  Any ideas on why this is having issues on mobile devices?  Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does your mobile device have a width of between 600 and 800 CSS pixels?

Comment: I ended up finding the issue.  I added an incorrect media query around the entire stylesheet for some reason.  Once I deleted it, everything loaded just fine on mobile. It was: @media (hover:hover) and (pointer: fine).  Just misused it :(

Answer (score 0):

sequence of css code is also very important.

e.g.

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    .brandImg .material-icons {font-size: 18px;}
    #openingAnimation::before {width: 60%;}
 }
 @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
     .navlinks {
         display: flex; 
         flex-flow: row wrap;
         justify-content: space-evenly;
       }
         .navlinks a {flex: 50%;}
  }


   .brandImg .material-icons {font-size: 22px;}
   #openingAnimation::before {width: 80%;}

   .navlinks {
         display: flex; 
         flex-flow: row wrap;
         justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    .navlinks a {flex: 580%;}
```

will not work. It should be as follows...

```
    .brandImg .material-icons {font-size: 22px;}
    #openingAnimation::before {width: 80%;}

   .navlinks {
         display: flex; 
         flex-flow: row wrap;
         justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    .navlinks a {flex: 580%;}

     @media screen and (max-width: 599px) {
        .brandImg .material-icons {font-size: 18px;}
        #openingAnimation::before {width: 60%;}
     }
    @media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
           .navlinks {
                 display: flex; 
                 flex-flow: row wrap;
            justify-content: space-evenly;
            }
            .navlinks a {flex: 50%;}
      }
```

so please check your whole css for sequence if @media is before or after.

Comment: I ended up finding the main issue just a little after I posted.  It seems I had an incompatible media query for hover set around entire css styles sheet by mistake @media (hover:hover) and (pointer: fine).  I rearranged the format as you suggested as well.  Thank you for your help.